# Definition of determinant shows that $\operatorname{det}\Lambda^n(R^n)=1$

Tags: determinant, tensors

Spivak says the following:

> The fact that $\operatorname{dim}\Lambda^n(R^n)=1$ is probably not new to you, since $\operatorname {det}$  is often defined as the unique element $\omega\in\Lambda^n(R^n)$ such that $\omega(e_1,\dots,e_n)=1$. For a general vector space $V$ there is no extra criterion of this sort to distinguish a particular $\omega\in\Lambda^n(V)$.

I'm trying to understand how it follows from this definition, that each $\omega\in\Lambda^n(R^n)$ is a multiple of a non-zero element of $\Lambda^n(R^n)$, because that is what it says. It seems that in a more-dimensional vector space, it's impossible to have a *unique* element, which portrays the basis vectors to 1. Could someone give me a hint on the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be an element of $\Lambda^n(\Bbb R^n)$ which is not a multiple of $\omega$. Define $g=\gamma(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ and pick an $a\in \Bbb R$ such that $a\neq 0,-\frac1g$. Then we have
$$
\frac{1}{1+ag}(\omega+a\gamma)(e_1,\ldots,e_n)=1
$$
but $\frac{1}{1+ag}(\omega+a\gamma)$ is not a multiple of $\omega$.

So since there is a unique $\omega$ such that $\omega(e_1,\ldots,e_n)=1$, all elements must be multiplies of $\omega$